# Is there any fundamental difference between piping in mac and linux?

Tags: mac, bash, shell

```
ps -e | grep bash
```

sample output from a linux machine:

```
1128 pts/14   00:00:00 bash
7491 pts/7    00:00:00 bash
12651 pts/14   00:00:00 bash
16145 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
```

sample output from a mac machine:

```
58352 ttys000    0:00.09 login -pfl username /bin/bash -c exec -la bash /bin/bash
58353 ttys000    0:00.02 -bash
58390 ttys000    0:00.00 grep bash
20372 ttys005    0:00.06 login -pfl username /bin/bash -c exec -la bash /bin/bash
20373 ttys005    0:00.18 -bash
```

My question is that why we see "grep bash" in the second case but not the first case.

Comment: how piping works is related to the program `bash`, how the output looks is related to `ps`. Maybe MacOS has a different version/variant of `ps` installed. Have you noted any difference in the output before piping?

Comment: What kind of linux? I vaguely remember getting the latter behaviour in ubuntu

Comment: On Linux I've seen this work one way one time and the other way the next time.  I think it has to do with the task IDs assigned as much as anything, though I can't offhand explain how.

Comment: Or probably it's a function of pipe buffer size and the thread list order.  In the first case `ps` had traversed beyond where it would find `grep` in the thread list before it filled the first pipe buffer.  Since it got kicked off first, it did this before `grep` was started.  In the second case the buffer was filled before the place where `grep` would be was reached in the task list.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce the Mac OS X behavior right now – it's likely related to process scheduling details in the OS, and might depend on timing and number of processors.

```
$ ps -e | grep bash
86880 ttys000    0:00.18 -bash
87718 ttys000    0:00.00 (bash)
```

Generally, OS X provides mostly BSD command-line programs, and Linux distributions bring the GNU variants. They are (mostly) compatible implementations of the same basic tools, but will behave differently, with often different features and arguments.

Given that the programs used (or versions in cases they're actually the same) are so different, I don't think it's possible to determine what causes the `grep bash` to show up on your system.

Comment: I get `grep bash` as well in the output, as I expected, because when I grep for something, I'll usually `grep -v grep` afterwards to get rid of that.

Comment: @slhck Thanks, added the *right now* to clarify. I'm used to this as well, therefore my assumption of timing/process scheduling being involved.

Comment: And actually I usually see the `grep <string>` when I `ps aux | grep <string>` in linux.

Answer (score 1):

In any case, the difference observed has nothing to do with the pipe and everything to do with `ps`. Try redirecting ps's output to a file and searching for the string there.

Comment: I suspect it has to do with pipe buffer size.

Comment: I doubt it, maybe this particular version of osx ps filters out the grep itself. Useful feature really. I just don't think it is piping that makes the difference.

Comment: How/why would ps "filter out" grep, vs any other task?  How does it know you're not looking for a hung grep to kill it?

Comment: Well, everyone knows `ps` stands for "precognitive software" :).  I have no idea what I was thinking...